# chainloader error in grub

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, grub

I'm trying to install Linux on my laptop. The problem being the BIOS is locked. I installed GRUB and now I want to boot my bootable Linux USB (Fedora 38) using grub2. I tried this:

`set root=(hd1,gpt1`

then

`chainloader +1`

to then hopefully boot it using the `boot` command. The issue is that `chainloader +1` gives an error:

`../../grub-core/kern/efi/sb.c:182:bad shim signature`

Answer (score 1):

You are following instructions intended for BIOS-style boot process, but your system runs in UEFI native mode, and might even have Secure Boot enabled.

Instead of loading and executing the first block of a disk or partition (i.e. a Master Boot Record or a Partition Boot Record respectively), UEFI boot process wants a *boot file* in a filesystem that is directly readable to the firmware. All versions of UEFI specification guarantee FAT32 support, and vendors have an option to add filesystem support above and beyond the UEFI spec requirements.

The standard boot file path on a removable media is `/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` starting from the root of the filesystem in question.

So, try `chainloader /EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` instead of `chainloader +1`.

Comment: thanks solved the issue

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! You should see a green checkmark next to answers to any questions posted by you. Wait two days or so (in case someone else posts a better answer), then click on the checkmark to mark the best answer to your question as the accepted one. Accepting an answer is worth 1.5 upvotes, so it also works as a thank-you.